# Helical "packing" of deltahedra?

Tags: geometry, applications, polyhedra, packing-problem

I'm looking for help with terminology:

I'm a glass artist / PhD researcher aiming to use a modular, geometric approach to making.  I've been looking to use repeated polyhedra (with regular polygonal faces) as a modular substructure to hold more complex 'decorative' units.

With so many options, I've initially limited myself to the convex deltahedra - and have been exploring how these can be put together. Rather than close packing, as is possible with the octahedron/tetrahedron, I'm interested in more loosely packed structures and formations. I found that I can create a wide variety of helical formations from pairs of the convex deltahedra. (Screen grabs of a two example CAD models below)

[image: Helix from Pentagonal Bipyramid and Octahedron]
[image: Helix from Pentagonal Bipyramid and Triangular Bipyramid]

With not having the correct words/terminology to describe these, I'm having trouble finding relevant work to read - or any areas of applied maths which might be relevant. I think that this is part of Topology - but is there a more specific area I should be looking at? And *are* these helices a form of packing - as the structure is only repeated in one rather than three dimensions? The closest thing I've found, is the Boerdijk-Coxeter helix - which does seem to relate to spherical packing.

Also are the radius and vertical offset the only characteristics which I need to specify in order to designate the underlying helix, or do I need to consider other characteristics?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though not exactly the same polyhedra, I advise you to read (as a Google book) in "Homage to a pied puzzler ", authors : Pegg, Schoen,  Rodgers (AK Peters editor) the article of Sandor Kabai, in particular his helices page 56. This books is (among others) a tribute to Martin Gardner. In fact with keywords "Sandor Kabai helix", you find many things on the web.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - looks like a rich vein of information to explore, and will hopefully help my maths vocabulary too.

Comment: A side remark : a fascinating book (google book) : The Nature of the Mechanical Bond: From Molecules to Machines by Carson J. Bruns, J. Fraser Stoddart

Comment: That's a brilliant recommendation!  Not sure my chemistry knowledge will hold up - but it's been written well, so there's hope.  Plus plenty of fascinating diagrams - and some more very useful applied vocabulary. Thank you for taking the time.